# GWT 2.3 client side rpc request modification

Tags: gwt-rpc

we are upgrading from gwt1.2 to gwt2.3. In earlier version we had modified the client side code which was dealing with POST request so that it can integrate with portal i.e. asyncPostImpl() method in HTTPRequestImpl.java..

but on gwt2.3, that implementation is no more.. i tried modifying in doSend() method in RequestBuilder and seems it is still not modifying.

Can anyone please help me pointing the equivalent class of HTTPRequestImpl in gwt 2.3 where request and response pass thru so that i can try modifying the code to make it working ?

Thanks
DK

Comment: hi, i got the place where the requests can be modified: 1) RequestBuilder.java --> used to modify the URL and postData/requestData 2) XMLHttpRequest.java --> the responseText can be modified..  thanks everyone